# How to prove $g$ is discontinuous at $x=2$ using definition of limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

Define $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$g(x) =\begin{cases}
5x-15 & \text{if } x \text{ is rational}, \\\\
   x^3-17       & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational}.
  \end{cases}$$

Prove that $g$ is discontinuous at $x=2$.

So, here's what I got before I got stuck:

$g(x)$ is continuous at $2$ if $g(2)$ exists and $g(2) = \lim\limits_{x\to 2} g(x)$.

By definition of the limit, $\lim\limits_{x\to 2} g(x) = L$.

So for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $|g(x)-g(2)| < \epsilon$, then $|x-2|<\delta$.

And now I'm just not sure how to continue the problem from here. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: I think you got the definition of continuity wrong...

Comment: Oh, I thought I could use definition of limit here :( guess I needed more help than I thought

Comment: I just want to point out two things: 1. By saying "$\lim_{x\to 2} g(x)=L$ for $L\in\mathbb{R}$" you already assumed existence of this limit. This is not clear and needs to be proven! (Actually that's the whole point.) 2. The sentence with $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ got mixed up. It's "$|x-2|<\delta\Rightarrow |g(x)-g(2)|<\varepsilon$", not the other way round. (Plus, this is what you want to show, not what you get. See 1. It's the definition of an _existing_ limit which is basically the same as continuity of a function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume instead that g is continuous at 2.  Then since $g(2)=5(2)-15=-5$, $\;\;\displaystyle \lim_{x\to2}g(x)=-5$;

so taking $\epsilon=1$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-2|<\delta$, then $\big|g(x)-(-5)\big|<1$.

Therefore if $x$ is irrational and $2-\delta<x<2$, then

$\big|(x^3-17)+5\big|<1\implies\big|x^3-12\big|<1\implies11<x^3<13\implies x^3>8\implies x>2$,

which gives a contradiction.

Therefore g is discontinuous at 2.

Comment: Why did you take $\epsilon = 1$?

Comment: Good question -- this was just an arbitrary choice; any $\epsilon$ with $0<\epsilon<4$ would have worked in this argument.

Comment: One more question. Why can we choose an $\epsilon$ between $0$ and $4$?

Comment: By our assumption, $\lim_{x\to2}g(x)=-5$, so for ANY $\epsilon>0$ there must be a corresponding $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-2|<\delta$, then $|g(x)-(-5)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Think I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let sequence $\{x_n\}$ be that $\{x_n\}\to5$ and $\{x_n\}$ is in irrational numbers. Then $f(x_n)=x_n^3-17$. Then $\lim f(x_n)=\lim(x_n^3-17)=5^3-17=108$. $f(5)=25-15=10$. So $f$ is not continuous at $x=5$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{n}\notin{\Bbb{N}}$.

So $2+\sqrt{n}$ is irrational, and we have:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to2^+}g(x)&=\lim_{n\to0}(2+\sqrt{n})^3-17\\&=\lim_{n\to0}8+12n^{1/2}+6n+n^{3/2}-17\\&=-9
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to2^-}g(x)&=\lim_{n\to0}(2-\sqrt{n})^3-17\\&=\lim_{n\to0}8-12n^{1/2}+6n-n^{3/2}-17\\&=-9
\end{align}

While for $x=2$ (rational),

$g(2)=5\cdot2-15=-5\neq-9$

Therefore the function is discontinuous at $x=2$